# How to Play Audio in Realtime in LMMS?

Tags: sound-effects, software

Changing the tempo directly (globally) or via an automation track only affects the readout and doesn't change the actual tempo, which seems to default to 140 BPM.

Is there a way I can get it to play in realtime, so 1 actual second progresses 1 second in the song?

Comment: How powerful is your computer and are you running through any special audio hardware?

Comment: @AJHenderson I'm actually on fairly low-end laptop and using no special audio equipment? Are low speced systems known to cause problems? It seems like it's handling LMMS fine.

Comment: UPDATE: Apparently, this is a bug with the version of LMMS (version 1.13) I'm using from PortableApps.com. The normal version of LMMS you can install doesn't have this problem. Funny thing is, on the installed version, everything plays at the default TEMPO/BPM, which is 140 BPM no matter what you set it to. And that's still faster than realtime, so I guess this  question still wouldn't be solved.

Comment: I would recommend editing this information in to your question.  It will make it easier for others to find and will help people more quickly determine the root of the question as it has shifted a bit.

Comment: @AJHenderson updated the information.